# Como fazer um painel com informações duplas com <tr>

Tags: html, html5

Eu consigo entender manuseio básico de `<tr>`, como no exemplo abaixo onde temos uma informação em cada linha.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid pink;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Opção 1</th>
    <th>Opção 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Mas como posso utilizar o `<tr>` para atingir o resultado do exemplo abaixo? Onde coloco duas informações na mesma linha (titulo e subtítulo) e ambos na mesma coluna?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é só adicionar duas colunas?

Comment: @Marconi Quero deixar dois textos. Um em baixo do outro sendo titulo e subtitulo, na mesma coluna e na mesma linha onde terão os outros componentes.

Comment: Não pode colocar cada texto numa tag `p` por exemplo?

Comment: algo assim (bem básico só pra ilustrar): http://jsfiddle.net/6fpwm52s/2/

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim

Comment: O exemplo dado como imagem não parece ser de dados tabulares. Por quê está utilizando tabelas?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss perdão mas, o que seriam dados tabulares? existe diferença do que abordar em uma tabela/em uma lista?

Comment: @hunterxhunter São dados que pertencem a uma tabela. Tabelas são utilizadas para apresentar dados que possuem correlação de forma a permitir que possam ser analisados e/ou comparados. Por exemplo, uma tabela de preços de diferentes planos, onde você apresenta as características e valores de cada um. Uma lista de itens não é uma tabela. A diferença está na semântica da sua página: uma lista seria melhor definida com os elementos `<ul>`, `<ol>` ou até um conjunto de `<div>`, dependendo do contexto.

Comment: Você pode desenhar uma porta em uma parede e me dizer que é uma porta. Eu irei acreditar que é uma porta, pois parece uma porta, mas é uma parede - isso resume a semântica do HTML.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss seu ultimo exemplo me fez compreender bem, obrigada. estudarei mais sobre isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara basicamente você adiciona mais 1 coluna. 
O css que adicionei foi apenas para se ficar similar a sua imagem.
**Lembre-se `th` e `td` não respeitam margin apenas o `td` respeita padding** de preferencia em alinhar os elementos internamente.

```css
td {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 50px;  
  height: 50px;
}

h4, p {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Hunter xhunter</h4>
      <p>usuário Stack Overflow Em PT</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4>Hunter xhunter</h4>
      <p>usuário Stack Overflow Em EN</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, coloquei aqui e funcionou, mas só mais uma coisa, como dou um pequeno espaçamento entre a imagem e as palavras? pq no meu elas ficaram grudadas.

Comment: Você deve usar um margin-right na imagem como no exemplo porque o td e o tr não respeitam margin, você poderia alterar o display para um mais flexivel mas acho que não é o seu caso.

Comment: esclarecedor. obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isto você precisa utilizar duas divs com CSS. A div por padrao ja possui quebra de linha com display: block. conforme exemplo você consegue atingir seu obetivo:

```html
   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid pink;
}
.title{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}
.sub-title{
font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Opção 1</th>
    <th>Opção 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="title">TITULO</div><div class="sub-title">SUB-TITULO</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: vc pode ser mais especifico? e de preferencia utilizar um modelo verificavel? eu estou aprendendo e falando assim não me ajuda muito.

Comment: sim vou postar um exemplo para voce

Comment: Ao invés de definir as classes "title" e "subtitle", por quê não utiliza os elementos `<h*>` e, assim, manter a semântica do HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa usar `<table>`, resolver apenas com **HTML** e precisa realmente separar o titulo e o texto em duas linhas... Pode usar `rowspan` e `colspan`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid pink;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  
  <!--Inicio Bloco -->
  <tr>  
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></td>    
    <td height="1px"><b>Hunter xhunter</b></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Hunter usuário Stack Overflow em PT</td>
  </tr>
  <!--Fim Bloco -->
  
  <tr><td colspan="2" height="10px"></td></tr>
  
  <!--Inicio Bloco -->
  <tr>  
    <td rowspan="2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></td>    
    <td height="1px"><b>Hunter xhunter</b></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Hunter usuário Stack Overflow em PT</td>
  </tr>
  <!--Fim Bloco -->
  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```